# Base64 for a hash algorithm

Tags: hash, sha-256, sha-1, md5, encoding

It may be a silly question, but I am really curious.

If a hash algorithm uses Base64 in the process of hashing a string, for example, it is still considered a hash algorithm, even though it uses an encoding algorithm in it's process?

Comment: I get the feeling that your question is poking at the surface of a deeper issue you're trying to understand. What's the context, and why is the nomenclature important here?

Comment: @StephenTouset I don't really understand your question... I just want an simple answer..

Comment: I know of no cryptographic hash algorithm ever made that uses Base64 in the hashing process

Comment: OTOT, many hash algorithms can be seen as operating in "base $2^{32}$" (or $2^{64}$). There's nothing that says one couldn't use base 64, it would just not be very efficient in software.

Comment: It is very common to post-process a hash's result using base64, and the resulting algorithm _could_ be considered a hash. If so, that resulting algorithm is a hash algorithm that uses Base64 in (the final phase of) the process of hashing a string. $\;$ That question has no clear-cut answer as stated.

Answer (score 5):

If you had an algorithm that used a Base64 conversion as a part of its processing, that would not be considered grounds for disqualifying it as a hash function (be it a cryptographical or noncryptographical hash). We consider a function to be a hash solely on the properties it has (statistical in the case of a noncryptographical hash; preimage, second preimage and collision resistance in the case of a cryptographical hash); the components that make it up are not considered relevant.

Now, I haven't heard of any hash that used a Base64 conversion internally.